# Erro em função cordova e AngularJS

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, apache-cordova

Segue abaixo o código que estou usando. É o exemplo padrão da função de checagem de conexão do Cordova.

```
    <script>
        angular.module("contato", []);
        angular.module("contato").controller("contatoCtrl", function($scope){

            $scope.app = "app";

            var checkConnection = function () {
                var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
                var states = {};
                states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
                states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
                states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
                states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
                states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
                states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

                console.log('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
                alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);


            };

            checkConnection();

        });

    </script>
```

Porem, tenho o seguinte erro:

```
angular.js:12450 TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at checkConnection (index.html:50)
    at new <anonymous> (index.html:67)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4476)
    at extend.instance (angular.js:9127)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8239)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7671)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7546)
    at angular.js:1662
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15922)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16022)
```

Obs>: Se a solução for retirar a função do angular e realizar como uma função javascript normal, também será bem vindo

Comment: você está tentando radar essa função em um navegador ou em um dispositivo celular ? Caso seja em um navegador o erro está ocorrendo pois o cordova não é detectado pelo navegador, tente rodar em um dispositivo e veja se o erro persiste.

Comment: Em ambos o erro persiste

Comment: Teria como você enviar a parte do código onde importa o cordova para seu projeto. Sugiro que dê uma olhada no ng-cordova e certifique-se de que o plugin de network esta instalado em seu projeto

Comment: Não estou usando o cordova for angular. estou usando o cordova puro

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Se `navigator.connection` está `undefined` provavelmente você esqueceu de adicionar o plugin de conexão no cordova:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/